# List goes from count of 1 to 0 between two operations, with no code to do so. (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I've got the following list

```
List<int> deletedRecords = new List<int>();
```

When I hit the delete button in my gridview, I add the Id for that record to this List.

When the user clicks the save button, all records that exist in the List are deleted from the database before I proceed.

However, when I get to this point, the List is always empty.

The List is only referenced in three places, those being its declaration, its .Add method, and a foreach to cycle through all values it contains.

When I do a debug, I can see the List.Count go to 1, but then when I hit the Save button, my Debug shows the List has gone to a count of 0.  I'm really confused by this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list variable / field only exists for the duration of a single request; any button-click (such as Save) is a *separate* request, with an entirely different set of objects. In many cases it won't even be served by the same server.

If you need state between requests, you need to *manage* that state, perhaps via session-state.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code, I'd guess the following:

**You've forgotten web apps have no state.**

Comment: @Matt: It means you need to think about the fact that to the server each request is independent of the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

As [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) and [Esteban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781/esteban-araya) said, you have to persist your items.

So instead of writing

```
List<int> deletedRecords = new List<int>();
```

you could write

```
private List<int> deletedRecords
{
    get
    {
        var result = ViewState["deletedRecords"] as List<int>;

        if ( result == null )
        {
            result = new List<int>();
            ViewState["deletedRecords"] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and use this property of your page class instead.

Comment: Sure, that's one way to manage state. Can't say I'd recommend it tho.

Comment: @Esteban How would you do it then?

Comment: I think Esteban is thinking "session state" rather than "view state" (or there are various other options). But in general *anything* is preferable to sending a blob of waste to/from the client every request. View-state was dreamt up by somebody who hates end-users.

Comment: Thanks, @Marc. Usually I'm using a "server-side" view state, which keeps the client-side size constant and small.